# FinalBuilder Enumeration of files and folders

Tags: finalbuilder

What's the best way to enumerate a set of files and folders using FinalBuilder?

The context of my question is, I want to compare a source folder with a destination folder, and replace any matching files in the destination folder that are older than the source folder.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok, for future reference, it turns out that under the catgeory "Iterators" there are two very helpful actions.

1. File/Fileset Iterator
2. Folder Iterator

Further digging revealed the Robocopy Mirror action, which does exactly what I was looking for, namely syncing the destination folder with the source folder. No need to write my own file iteration routines.